# Issue in creating portlet using SDK plugin in liferay

Tags: sdk, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have installed liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2-ce-ga3-20130816114619181.zip and liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1-20130816114619181.zip in same path say "/home/sim/Desktop/LR". And tried to install SDK plugin from  http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installing-the-sdk

When i tried to create portlet

```
 /Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets$ ./create.sh newportlet "My New Portlet" 
   Buildfile: /home/sim/Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/build.xml
   [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar
 [get] To: /home/sim/Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/.ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar
```

then i manually dowloded file ivy-2.3.0.jar

```
  wget  http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar--2013-09-25 15:15:00--  http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar
  Resolving www-proxy.ericsson.se (www-proxy.ericsson.se)... 153.88.253.150
  Connecting to www-proxy.ericsson.se (www-proxy.ericsson.se)|153.88.253.150|:8080... connected.
  Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
  Length: 1222059 (1.2M) [application/java-archive]
  Saving to: `ivy-2.3.0.jar'
    100%[=====================================================================================================>] 1,222,059    204K/s   in 5.9s    
  2013-09-25 15:15:06 (203 KB/s) - `ivy-2.3.0.jar' saved [1222059/1222059]
```

Then i again ran

```
 /Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets$ ./create.sh newportlet "My New Portlet"
```

Getting No error... It got stuck here..

```
  Buildfile: /home/sim/Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/portlets/build.xml
  [ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0 - 20130110142753 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
  [ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = /home/sim/Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/ivy-settings.xml
```

Anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Plugins SDK is not getting stuck, but rather it is downloading all of the dependencies needed.  The Plugins SDK needs several megabytes worth of jar files that it needs to build plugins.  Notice when it appears 'stuck' its actually download jars into the `/home/sim/Desktop/LR/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/.ivy/cache/` folder.

You should just let the process complete and then from now own the .ivy/cache folder will contain everything it needs and it wont have to download again.

Also you can share/copy that same .ivy/cache file into other folders in the future to save the download time.

Answer (score 2):

As Gregory Amerson said on the [official LifeRay forum thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/35690851#_19_message_34128862), **you can try downloading this file** :

> http://files.liferay.org.es/staged/public-files/liferay-ide/dependencies/files/ivy-cache.zip

You will have to **unzip** it and **replace** the `.ivy` folder in your liferay-plugins-sdk folder.

Hope this helps.

J.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the SDK portlets are installed in

```
/home/sim/Desktop/LR
```

But for some reason the ivy-settings.xml is looked up in

```
/home/esingso/Desktop/LR
```

So some of your settings are inconsistent.

Most probably, this is caused by using multiple accounts, eg. like firing the ./create.sh command logged as 'esingso' instead of 'sim'

Comment: Hey i actually did that only. keeping both all the files in same path /home/sim/Desktop/LR. This was typo mistake actually. But same problem exists

Comment: it's been 9 days since I've answered that and I don't remember the issue, sorry